# Differentability and continuity of a multivariate function

Tags: calculus

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^3_{u,v,w}$ $\to \mathbb{R}^3_{x,y,z}$ be a map given by

$x = p(u, v, w)$,

$y = q(u, v, w)$,

$z = r(u, v, w)$,

where $p$, $q$, and $r$ are polynomials in the variables $u$, $v$, $w$.

(a) Is $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^3$

(b) Is it true that $f$ is also differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^3$

What i think
is that the equation above, u,is a subset of x,v is a subset of y and w is a subset of z, and since x, y ,z are polynomials, they must be continuous implying that u,v,w are also continuous.And that the function maps nicely thus i got the feeling that it might be continuous. But im unsure though as to how to tackle this problem. Do i have to use the squeeze theorem to prove that limit of the function exists.I know that continuous means that the curve is a smooth one with no holes breaks in between and that the limit exists at all point of the curve but im unsure how to apply it to this question. Could anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any polynomial 
$$
P(x,y,z) = \sum_{i_1+i_2+i_3 \leq N} a_{i_1 i_2 i_3} x^{i_1}y^{i_2}z^{i_3}
$$
is a $C^\infty$ function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. This follows immediately from the fact that $(x,y,z) \mapsto x$, $(x,y,z) \mapsto y$ and $(x,y,z) \mapsto z$ are $C^\infty$ functions, and the usual rules about differentiability of powers and sums.

You have a vector-valued function, which is differentiable if and only if each of its components is. Hence your function $f$ is of class $C^\infty$.